# How to Works with files in different format like csv, xlsx,json,google docs using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in Node.js development and i don't know how to import files in different file formats like: csv, json, excel, google doc from different sources like url,google docs, local drive using Node.js. Any help related to this will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question for one of the issues you've raised? As is, this is much too broad for StackOverflow. It seems like you want others to locate all of the resources necessary to build your app as the question is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

- [excel](https://npmjs.org/package/excel) (For CSV-Files, XLSX...) **npm-package**
- [fast-csv](https://npmjs.org/package/fast-csv) (only for CSV-Files) **npm-package**
- for JSON you can simply use `JSON.parse`
- to access local-files there is [FS](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)
- google-docs/drive... [node-google-api](https://npmjs.org/package/node-google-api), [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/samcday/node-google-spreadsheets)